# Avoid ListView Item duplicacy

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to show some items followed by its sub-items in ListView. For this I have passed the Collection(ArrayList) to the ListView Adapter class for showing each items. And for sub-items I have to get data from SQLite database by the help of each position Id and create dynamic views for each sub-item. Fortunately its showing all items and sub items, but multiple times. Also after loading when I clicked some dynamic view, the list created the same view again 3/4 times.

Adapter Class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    if(convertView == null){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customincidentquestion, null);         
        mViewHolder.customLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutCustomIncidentQuestionList);
        mViewHolder.question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    ArrayList<IncidentOptionHolder> mOptionCollection = new ArrayList<IncidentOptionHolder>();
    ArrayList<String> optionText = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> orderedId = new ArrayList<String>();
    Log.v("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));
    IncidentQuestionHolder mHolder = mQuestionData.get(position);
    String mServerId = mQuestionData.get(position).getId();
    Log.e("mServerId", mQuestionData.get(position).getId());



    String mQText = mHolder.getqText();
    Log.e("mQText", mQText);
    String mType = mHolder.getType();
    String mOrderId = mHolder.getOrderId();
    String mIsMandatory = mHolder.getIsMandatory();
    String mIsOption = mHolder.getIsOption();

            Log.v("Equality", "Not Equal");
            IncidentOption mOptions = new IncidentOption(mContext);
            mOptions.open();
            mOptionCollection = mOptions.getOptions(mServerId);
            mOptions.close();

            //if(mViewHolder.customLayout.getChildAt(0) == null){
                mViewHolder.question.setText(mQText);
            for (int i = 0; i < mOptionCollection.size(); i++) {
                //optionText.add(mOptionCollection.get(i).getOptionText());
                //orderedId.add(mOptionCollection.get(i).getOrderId());
                Log.e("mOptionCollection.get(i).getOptionText()", mOptionCollection.get(i).getOptionText());


                if (mType.equals("Cb")) {
                    Log.v("TYPE", "Check Box");
                    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ll.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    CheckBox product = new CheckBox(mContext);
                    product.setText(mOptionCollection.get(i).getOptionText());
                    product.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    product.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_designs);
                    product.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 30);
                    ll.addView(product);
                    mViewHolder.customLayout.addView(ll);
                }

                else if (mType.equals("Ta")) {
                    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ll.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    Log.v("TYPE", "Text Box");
                    LinearLayout lll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                    lll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
                    tv.setText(mOptionCollection.get(i).getOptionText());
                    lll.addView(tv);

                    EditText ta = new EditText(mContext);

                    ta.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    ta.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_designs);
                    lll.addView(ta);
                    ll.addView(lll);
                    mViewHolder.customLayout.addView(ll);
                }

                else if (mType.equals("Rb")) {
                    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ll.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    Log.v("TYPE", "Radio Button");
                    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(mContext);
                    rb.setText(mOptionCollection.get(i).getOptionText());
                    rb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    rb.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 30);
                    rb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_designs);
                    ll.addView(rb);
                    mViewHolder.customLayout.addView(ll);
                }
                else{
                    Log.v("TYPE", "Nothing");
                }


            }


    return convertView;


}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout customLayout = null;
    public TextView question;
}
```

For sub-items I don't need to use Expandable List.

Can any suggest me where I did the mistake which force the ListView to load the same items multiple times.

Comment: ArrayList<IncidentOptionHolder> mOptionCollection = new ArrayList<IncidentOptionHolder>();
    ArrayList<String> optionText = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> orderedId = new ArrayList<String>(); move this lines out of getView(). Declare them inside class before constuctor and give a try. Evry time you are creating list. This may be the cause

Comment: @EagleEye I have tried it. But unfortunately its not working. The result is the same as before.

Comment: Are you sure that  *mOptionCollection* and *mQuestionData* don't have duplicated items?

Comment: @Rami Yes I'm sure. The collection has the data which come from my local DB. As I know the issue is coming by calling getView method multiple times. I don't know why the getView calling multiple times and the position is sometimes same also..

Comment: The number of items (only items not the sub-items) in your ListView (UI), is it equal to the size of the ArrayList that you have passed to the adapter?

Comment: Yes, The number of items is 4. Also the ArrayList size is 4. Both are same.

Comment: try to remove *if(convertView == null){}else{}* , and just keep the code inside the "IF" bloc. With this change , getView() will inflate a new view for each item... you'll lose some performance in your code but it can solve your problem! give a try.

Comment: @Rami `just keep the code inside the "IF" bloc. With this change` ..I didn't understand this approach.. can you please explain a little bit more.

Comment: Remove if(){...}else{...} and replace it by : mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customincidentquestion, null);         
        mViewHolder.customLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutCustomIncidentQuestionList);
        mViewHolder.question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);